# Software Updater screen not Showing all details

Tags: unity

I did a complete reinstall of Ubuntu 16.10 and my details information screen on Software Updates are showing up with a small window for the progress.

[image: Screenshot of details on Software Update screen]

Anyone know how to fix this? I think it is happening in other places as well.

Answer (score 1):

It has already been reported.  You can see the status here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1623856